# Inserting a table data inside the function

Tags: list-manipulation, data

Consider a table with n columns and function f[x] depending on n coordinates, $x = x_{1},...,x_{n}$. I want to interpret the table as a set of points in n-dimensional space and calculate the function f[] at each point from the set. Does there exist any command which allows me to do this in one string?

The table is the dataset `{{x11, x12, x13, ...}, {x21, x22, x23, ...}}`, and I would like to associate the number of the row with the coordinate set in n-dimensional space, so that `f[5] -> f[x51, x52, x53, ...]`.

Comment: 1) What do you mean by _string_? [`String`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/String.html) in MMA is a well defined command. 2) If your data is, e.g., `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`, then `f @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`.

Comment: @corey979 : sorry, I meaned a row of the table.

Comment: @corey979 : I've added some information to the question, please be so kind to read it.

Comment: `f[n_] := dosomething[table[[n]]]` would go in that general direction.

Comment: That doesn't change much in the approach, but makes the issue more precise. Note you cannot have the symbol `f` in two meanings like in the very last part of your question. You can do (with, e.g., `data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`): `g[k_] := (f @@@ data)[[k]]`. Then `g[1]` yields `f[1,2]` etc. With your definition of `f` you'll have `g[5]` yielding `f[x51,x52,x53,....]` etc.

Comment: Or, in order not to compute `f @@@ data` every time: `h[k_] := f @@ data[[k]]`, then `h[2]` yields `f[3, 4]` etc.

Comment: You have already defined the function f[x] somehow, have not you? As much as I understand this prevents you from defining the function returning you f[5] = f[x51, x52, x53, ...] if it is denoted by the same symbol. What about another symbol? Say, `g=Map[f,lst]` and then `g[[5]]` returns you `f[{x51, x52, x53, ...}]' ?